# kodak easyshare printer dock series 3

Tags: drivers, printing

I have a Kodak easyshare printer dock series 3, and I would like to print with it using ubuntu.  I looked on the OEM website but did not find a driver.
when I plugged it in, Ubuntu messaged me that the appropriate driver was not found. Is there support anywhere for this device as a photo printer?

(I can get it to print, text only with a generic driver but... you know)

Ubuntu Mate 17.04

Answer (score 1):

In printer add, when I was presented with the option for generic (recommended),
I instead went to: Kodak, and looked in there. I saw a generic option for Kodak+GutenPrint, and a listing for the "easyshare printer dock".
I selected these things, and it prints fine photos now.